# Efficiently creating code to calculate relative error

Tags: r, aggregate

The overall purpose of my code is calculate the pixel-scale relative errors after aggregating a fine-resolution map to a coarse-resolution map. To accomplish this, I have already created a data frame (here labelled as df) that at least put these numbers together. Next, I wanted to calculate the relative error for each coarse-resolution pixel, and to do that I need to calculate the root-mean squared error between the coarse pixel and the fine pixels it contains, as well as the mean of the fine pixels it contains. This then needs to iterate over all of the coarse pixels.

While I do have this problem solved with a for loop (see below), it is not the most optimal piece of code, especially because the data frame is rather large (mainly because I am looking over a large area of interest).

I believe the more efficient approach uses by() or maybe aggregate()?, but I am not sure how this can be performed. I have tried adapting the code (specifically the for loop) towards these function, but have had no success. Any thoughts on how to make it work with by()?

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(FineSP@data,extract$cells,extract$coarseval))

names(df)[1] <- "fine_res_values"
names(df)[2] <- "cellnumber"
names(df)[3] <- "coarse_res_values"

df$cellnumber <- as.character(df$cellnumber)

uniquecells<-unique(df$cellnumber) 

rmse_user <- function(fine, coarse){ # user fuction to calculate root-mean squared error

  rmse_fun = sqrt( mean( (fine - coarse)^2, na.rm = TRUE) ) 

  return(rmse_fun)

}

relative_error_user <- function(fine, coarse){ # user fuction to calculate pixel-scale relative error

  relative_error_value <- round(rmse_user(fine, coarse) / mean(fine), 3)

  return(relative_error_value)

}

relerror_compile <- vector()
i<-1
for(i in 1:length(uniquecells)){

  filter <- df[which(df$cellnumber == uniquecells[i]),]  # subset data frame by matching cell numbers
  relerror_compile[i] <- relative_error_user(fine = filter$fine_res_values, coarse = filter$coarse_res_values) # apply the user-based function for relative error

}

# Initial (and unsuccessful) attempt to use by() as the alternative

by_test <-by (df$fine_res_values,list(df$cellnumber),FUN=function(z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate can do this, but have you considered the plyr package? Personally, I find it more 'user-friendly':

```
df <- data.frame(cellnumber=rep(1:3,each=4),
                 fine_res_value=rnorm(12,10,5),
                 coarse_res_value=rnorm(12,10,5))

library(plyr)
RE <- ddply(df,'cellnumber',function(x){round(sqrt( mean( (x$fine - x$coarse)^2, na.rm = TRUE) ) / mean(x$fine), 3)} )
```